# What DNS records must exist in order for a server to receive mail?

Tags: domain-name-system

My server has stopped receiving mail and i'm not sure why because i'm not familiar with DNS.

I'm using pointhq to add DNS rules manually and the server does everything as it should except receive mail.

Would someone be able to explain which DNS rules are needed?

Thanks!

Comment: You need an MX record and an A record that point to your email server.

Comment: @joeqwerty I current have: A mail.domain.com. ip & MX domain.com.  mail.domain.com. Would that be correct?

Comment: this isn't a good question.. it's like asking a mechanic.. give me all the reasons that a car won't start

Comment: @Mike Apparently, there are never any good questions for stackoverflow :( I tried to make it as simple as possible for SO's "question/answer format" That's why i'm not asking "why my car won't start" but rather, "My car won't start.. which spark plugs do I need for my car"

Comment: If you tell us your domain (assuming it is public facing) we can do nslookups and tell you what it wrong.
As far as I am aware you only need an MX record which can point to an IP address.
What you have might be correct, depending on exactly what you have entered.
For example there is a difference between "domain.com." and "domain.com"   The trailing dot can be a big deal in DNS.

Comment: Oooh. 
You'd also need an NS record.
Also it is normal to have a network type (which is usually "IN") in most DNS resource records, and a preference for a MX record.
If your examples in your comment to joeqwerty are literal then I don't think they'd work.

Comment: This is a classic case of [The X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912). Please read that, and then edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a working MX:

```
MX      10 willow.faerywicca.se.
```

In short, you need an MX record. That MX record needs to point to a resolvable address. You also need to have working NS records and glue records.

If you have this and it still isn't working, you need to post further information. Start by giving your actual domain name; it's impossible to figure out what may be going wrong while you're obfuscating the necessary information.